# Attaching two boxes together in CSS

Tags: css, position, positioning, html

I have a website design I'm trying to build right now, and I have a menu that is on the right. Here's the code and I'll explain after that.

```
#rightmenu {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    width:30px;height:578px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-580px;
}
```

So that is the menu that will be on the right, and I want it to attach to this box, and always go where it goes

```
#content {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    width:800px;height:auto;
    min-height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The width is at 800 and it just centers on the screen, so I need the 'rightmenu' to attach to the centered content box. Here's what it looks like at 800px(the proper way it should look):
[image: Proper]

Here's the way it looks if the web browser is smaller than 800px(which is the minimum size the web page will go):

[image: It's hard to see the rightmenu, but if you look closely you can see a line through everything which is it's right border]

And finally, here's the way it will go if the web is larger than 800px:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping them both in a div with a width of 830px and then place the "margin-right: auto; and margin-left: auto" properties on that wrapper.

Comment: When I saw that, I felt like an idiot that I didn't think of that, but then it didn't exactly work as I planned it would.

EDIT - I totally screwed it up, I'm going to try again.

Comment: Once I got that, my hardest problem ended up being getting the links in a vertical list rotated at 90 degrees, but with a question here and some playing around with it, I figured it out. Now I've got to figure out the color system, which is quite the challenge when you're color blind haha. Thanks, again.